# EF scaffolding MS SQL Views

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, scaffolding

does someone know a way to stop EF, generating this

`entity.HasNoKey();` line of code on views when the **Scaffold-DbContext** command is used.
My first thought on this was to just add a primary key to the views, but as I understand there is no way to do so.

Comment: It is updatable views? If no, why it is a problem?

Comment: Yes, the views should be updatable.

Comment: Looking at the source code. There is no easy way. You have to replace somehow `IScaffoldingModelFactory` with derived implementation of `RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory`